# Sequelize, error: inserción o actualización en la tabla «contracts» viola la llave foránea «contracts_travelId_fkey»

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize.js

Tengo el error

> detail: 'La llave (travelId)=(6) no está presente en la tabla «travels».'

pero según la relación establecida, *travelId* está en la tabla de *contrat*, no en *travel*.
Relaciones:
`Travel.hasMany(Contract)`
`Contract.belongsTo(Travel, { foreignKey: 'travelId' }); // coloca travelId en contract`

No estoy segura de dónde está el error. Mi ruta para agregar un viaje y que a la vez actualice los contratos agregando el id del viaje al que pertenece es la siguiente:

```
// Función para crear un nuevo viaje (POST)
    const createViaje = async (req, res, t) => {
      try {
        const {
          hotel,
          ubicHotel,
          fotosHotel,
          videoHotel,
          estadia,
          cronograma,
          menu,
          coordinador,
        } = req.body;
    
        // Crea el nuevo viaje y obtiene su ID
        const newViaje = await Travel.create(
          {
            hotel,
            ubicHotel,
            fotosHotel,
            videoHotel,
            estadia,
            cronograma,
            menu,
            coordinador,
          },
          { transaction: t }
        );
    
        return newViaje; // Devuelve el objeto del viaje creado
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Algo salió mal al crear el viaje:", error);
        throw error; // Lanza una excepción para desencadenar el rollback
      }
    };
    
    // Función para actualizar contratos con el ID del viaje creado (PUT)
    const updateContratos = async (req, res) => {
      const t = await sequelize.transaction();
      try {
        const contratos = JSON.parse(req.body.contratos);
        // Llama a la función POST (createViaje) para crear el viaje
        const newViaje = await createViaje(req, res, t);
        // Verifica si la creación del viaje se completó con éxito
        if (!newViaje || !newViaje.id) {
          // Si la creación del viaje falla, lanza una excepción para desencadenar el rollback
          throw new Error("La creación del viaje falló");
        }
        // Captura el travelId del viaje creado
        const newViajeId = newViaje.id;
        console.log("soy newViajeId ",newViajeId);
        //verifica que contratos sea un array
        if (Array.isArray(contratos)) {
          const putContratos = await Promise.all(
            contratos.map(async (el) => {
        //Actualiza los valores en contratos
              return Contract.update(
                { travelId: newViajeId },
                {
                  where: {
                    num: el,
                  },
                },
                { transaction: t }
              );
            })
          );
          // Confirma la transacción si todas las operaciones se completaron con éxito
          await t.commit();
          res.send(putContratos);
        } else {
          // Deshace la transacción si contratos no es un array válido
          await t.rollback();
          res.status(400).send({ mensaje: "Los contratos no son un array válido" });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Algo salió mal al actualizar los contratos:", error);
    
        // Deshace la transacción si ocurre un error
        await t.rollback();
        res.status(500).send({ mensaje: "Hubo un error al actualizar los contratos: ", error });
      }
    };
    
    module.exports = {
      updateContratos
    };
```

Mis modelos:

````
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
    // Exportamos una funcion que define el modelo
    // Luego le injectamos la conexion a sequelize.
    module.exports = function(sequelize) {
      // defino el modelo
      return sequelize.define('contract', {
        id:  {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        num: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true
          },
        
        fecha: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:false
        },
        curso: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true
        },
        division: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true
        },
        turno: {
           type:DataTypes.STRING,
           allowNull:true
        },
        colegio: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        }, 
        pasajeros: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },      
        mes: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        año: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        periodo: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        destino: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        impTot: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        canc: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        realiz: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        hotel: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        duracion: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        fechaFirma: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        fechaViaje: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        ImpTotAct: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        fechaActu: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        usuarioLog: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        fechaLog: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        id_sucursal: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },  
        id_periodo: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        },
        id_cotizacion: {
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:true
        }
      })
      };```
    ```const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
    // Exportamos una funcion que define el modelo
    // Luego le injectamos la conexion a sequelize.
    module.exports = function(sequelize) {
      // defino el modelo
      return sequelize.define('travel', {
        id:  {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
        },
        hotel: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          },
        
        ubicHotel: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        fotosHotel: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        videoHotel: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        estadia: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        cronograma: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        menu: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        coordinador: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        inicioViaje: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        ultimaUbic: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        finViaje: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        },
        muro: {
          type:DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull:true,
        }
      })
    
      };
````

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?